# How to force refresh of an AngularJS component

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-components

I developed an AngularJS component in my Ionic app. The component is called "friends".

The component executes code when one of its attributes changes (typically a filter value for instance).

```
.component('friends', {
bindings: {
  filter: '@' 
},
template:
`
<div ui-sref="nextView">
  {{results}}
</div>
`,
 controller: function(GroupService, $q, $ionicLoading) {
   this.$onInit = function() {
     this.updateView();
   }

   this.$onChanges = function(changesObj) {
     this.updateView();
   }

   this.updateView = function() { /*this.results is updated here */ }

  }})
```

When clicking the result the app opens a new view from which I can come back via a back button.

How can I force the component to refresh (execute the "updateView()") when coming back to this page?

**** EDIT ****
To clarify.

1/ The user arrives on TabA which HTML contains the component "friends". $onInit gets called and execute the updateView() that updates the variable "results".

2/ When user click on the component "friends" a sub-view of the TabA is displayed (via ui-sref).

3/ User come back from the sub-view to the TabA (thanks to a back-button on the sub-view). As the sub-view was "attached" to the TabA the $onInit of the component "friends" is not called BUT I want the updateView() function to be called again. So my question is, how can I trigger the updateView() on the component's controller when coming back from sub-view to TabA?

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say "when coming back to this page?". Component was not shown and now it appears? Was it hidden by ngShow?

Comment: Hi Sharikov, I just added some additional info. Hope this helps

Comment: You should read about [lifecycle hooks in ionic 1](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/order-of-lifecycle-events/28251). In your case beforeEnter hook could help as I see.